# How to match a string to pattern "Foo-Bar", where Bar can be any element of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of strings L.

I need to check, whether a string is either directly an element of L or is in this format: "foo-element_of_L"

Is there a better way to do this in python than adding "foo-X" to L for all X in L?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do two lookups:

```
if x in L or f'foo-{x}' in L:
```

which may be significantly faster than

```
if any(x == y or f'foo-{x}' == y for x in L):
```

which is essentially what you were proposing.